# Django CSFR verification

Tags: django, nginx, https, django-authentication

I'm trying to set up a registration form on my site using nginx and gunicorn with Django. I've got the registration working when I connect with http, but I get the following error over https:

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Reason given for failure:
Referer checking failed - https://<domainname>/register does not match https://127.0.0.1:8000/.

In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request 

Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:
Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function passes a request to the template's render method.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
```

My nginx config is as follows:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name <domainname>.co.uk www.<domainname>.co.uk;

    access_log off;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    location /static/ {
        alias /www/<domainname>/www/static/;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the `X-Forwarded-Host` header to gunicorn, but Django does not use this header by default. Django then uses the `HTTP_HOST` header, which does not match the referrer.

To use the `X-Forwarded-Host` header, set `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST` to `True` in your settings.